# Public Beta Availability

Tags: release-juno

Is it possible to apply for access to the Public Beta of V6 when it becomes available?
I run elementary OS on a VM Ware virtual machine on my iMac with great joy.

Answer (score 1):

You can run elementary OS 6 by [joining the Early Access program](https://builds.elementary.io/) and downloading a daily snapshot. One way to join is by becoming a [GitHub sponsor](https://github.com/sponsors/elementary).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an application process.
Anyone who wants to should be able to access the beta when it is released, if my understanding is correct.

As *pion* answered, you can easily get access to elementary OS 6 right now through the Early Access Program by becoming a GitHub sponsor of the project.
You are also welcome to otherwise build your own elementary OS 6 images or configure an Ubuntu 20.04 system with elementary's PPA's and the necessary packages.

Comment: Others should able to download beta anytime, sponsored users should get automatic notification. Donation is a good thing, restricting access is not.